# for loop is skipping to the end?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am fairly new to Java, but my for loop is instantly skipping to the highest possible value in the following code:

```
System.out.println(i);
    for(i = 0; i <= (difficulty - 2); i++);{
        System.out.println(i);
        nextMineX = (int) (10*Math.random());
        nextMineY = (int) (10*Math.random());

        for(y = 0; y <= 14; y++){
            System.out.println(y);
            if(nextMineX == minesX[y] && nextMineY == minesY[y]){
                i = i-1;
            } else{
                minesX[i] = nextMineX;
                minesY[i] = nextMineY;
            }
        }
    }
```

The first for loop is screwing up, while the nested one is running fine. the variable i is initialized as 0, and difficulty is at 16. the output of this excerpt is as follows:

```
0
14
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

If anyone can help me with his that would be extremely appreciated. Since I'm new, it is probably something small and basic that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Error is caused by typo. `for(i = 0; i <= (difficulty - 2); i++);{` Remove the semicolon between `);{` - that terminates the loop body and opens a new block.

Comment: Thank you Elliott. That was definitely it! Don't quite know how i missed that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is the semicolon at the end of the second line. It's valid to have a `for` loop with no body. It's also valid to have standalone a block of code inside brackets (this defines a scope for variables--if you defined a variable inside the brackets, it wouldn't be available outside). So Java is interpreting the beginning of your code like this:

```
for(i = 0; i <= (difficulty - 2); i++); // for loop is done, so i = difficulty - 2

{
    System.out.println(i);
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Your for loop statement ends with the semicolon you have

```
for(i = 0; i <= (difficulty - 2); i++); <- incorrect

for(i = 0; i <= (difficulty - 2); i++){ <- correct
     //body
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For loop is terminating cause of **semicolon ;**

```
for(i = 0; i <= (difficulty - 2); i++); //semicolon terminating loop
{...}
```

so you should use for loop like this

```
for(i = 0; i <= (difficulty - 2); i++) //remove semicolon prevent to terminate
    {...}
```